# Rails update action does not update boolean field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, form-for

In my Rails app I have a nested `form_for` in my show action. This form is the same as the one in the edit action, but it has different fields.

`Category -> Task -> completed (boolean, check_box)` is what I am trying to update, but it doesn't. Although, if I do `Category -> Task -> name (string, text_field)` it updates fine.

**This does NOT work**

```
<%= form_for check_list do |f| %>
  <%= f.error_messages %>
  <% count = 0 %>
  <ol>
  <%= f.fields_for :tasks do |task| %>
    <li>
      <%= task.label :completed, check_list.tasks[count].name %>
      <%= task.check_box :completed %>
    </li>
    <% count += 1 %>
  <% end %>
  </ol>
  <p><%= f.submit 'Update' %></p>
<% end %>
```

**This works**

```
<%= form_for check_list do |f| %>
  <%= f.error_messages %>
  <% count = 0 %>
  <ol>
  <%= f.fields_for :tasks do |task| %>
    <li>
      <%= task.label :name, check_list.tasks[count].name %>
      <%= task.text_field :name %>
    </li>
    <% count += 1 %>
  <% end %>
  </ol>
  <p><%= f.submit 'Update' %></p>
<% end %>
```

This is a partial, and `check_list` is a variable I'm passing

**Edit:**
Here is the source for my models:

```
class CheckList < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :tasks, :dependent => :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :tasks, :reject_if => lambda { |a| a[:name].blank? }, :allow_destroy => true

  # Validations
  validates :name, :presence => true

end

class Task < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :check_list
end
```

Comment: Could you paste the source code of your models?

Comment: Does it work if you remove the `:reject_if` condition?

Comment: Yes, it works when I remove `:reject_if`.

Comment: Are you using a state machine with your task model?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd suggest adding the name as a hidden field on the form, as Rails probably updates all the fields that are passed into the Action.

```
<%= form_for check_list do |f| %>
  <%= f.error_messages %>
  <% count = 0 %>
  <ol>
  <%= f.fields_for :tasks do |task| %>
    <li>
      <%= task.label :completed, check_list.tasks[count].name %>
      <%= task.check_box :completed %>
      <%= task.hidden_field :name %>
    </li>
    <% count += 1 %>
  <% end %>
  </ol>
  <p><%= f.submit 'Update' %></p>
<% end %>
  <% end %>
  </ol>
  <p><%= f.submit 'Update' %></p>
<% end %>
```